# SQLite Query Display Name with WHERE condition - Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am currently learning sqlite and I've been working with sqlite manager so far.

I have different tables and want to select all Project Names where 3 or more people have worked on.

I have my project table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "Project" 
("Project-ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , "Name" TEXT, "Year" INTEGER)
```

And I have my relation where it is specified how many people work on a project:

```
CREATE TABLE "Works_on" 
("User" TEXT, "Project-ID" INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(User) REFERENCES People(User), 
FOREIGN KEY(Project-ID) REFERENCES Project(Project-ID), PRIMARY KEY(User, Project-ID))
```

So in the simple view (sadly I can not upload Images) you have something like this in the relation "Works_on":

```
User   | Project-ID
-------+-----------
Greg   | 1
Daniel | 1
Daniel | 2
Daniel | 3
Jeny   | 3
Mark   | 3
Mark   | 1
```

Now I need to select the names of the projects where 3 or more people are working on, this means I need the name of project 3 and 1.

I tried so far to use count() but I can not figure out how to get the names:

```
SELECT Project-ID, count(Project-ID) 
FROM Works_on 
WHERE Project-ID >= 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Project-ID, t1.Name
FROM Project AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT Project-ID
   FROM Works_on 
   GROUP BY Project-ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) AS t2 ON t1.Project-ID = t2.Project-ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked, but damn, so far away from my initial solution, still have to learn a lot. Will accept in 5 min.

Answer (score 1):

You need join and  group by with a having clause like this:

```
SELECT t.project-id,t.name
FROM project t
INNER JOIN works_on s
 ON(t.project-id = s.project-id)
GROUP BY t.project-id,t.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Group works on project ID and count users (i.e. records). Keep project IDs with 3 or more users. Then select from project where the project ID is among the found ones.

```
select name
from project
where "Project-ID" in
(
  select "Project-ID"
  from works_on
  group by "Project-ID"
  having count(*) >= 3
);
```

"Project-ID" is a bad column name by the way. You need quotes everytime so as to stop the DBMS from interpreting this as a minus operation. Name it `project_id` or something alike instead.